# Directive Controller is Showing Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I intend to focus on usage of Directive Controller only. So, pl answer around the same error as mentioned as I suppose for each instance of directive usage, angular would go once in controller section mentioned in Directive.

```js
//module declaration 
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.name = "Peter";
});

//app declaration
app.directive('myStudent',function(){
return{
 template: "Hi! Dear!! {{name}}<br/>",
 controller:function(scope, elem, attr){
  console.log("controller");
 }
}
});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

<my-student></my-student> 
<my-student></my-student> 
<my-student></my-student> 
<my-student></my-student> 
<my-student></my-student> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Note:**

> Kindly, throw light on error and on usage of directive controller only. I know same can be done by pre-link, post-link, or compile.

PS: I dont understand the vote-down from some extra-terrestrial Genius!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it should be link function instead of controller.

```js
//module declaration 
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

//controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Peter";
});

//app declaration
app.directive('myStudent', function() {
  return {
    template: "Hi! Dear!! {{name}}<br/>",
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      console.log("controller");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <my-student></my-student>
  <my-student></my-student>
  <my-student></my-student>
  <my-student></my-student>
  <my-student></my-student>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

> Best Practice: use controller when you want to expose an API to other directives. Otherwise use link.

Controller accepts an array:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

//controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Peter";
});

//app declaration
app.directive('myStudent', function() {
  return {
    template: "Hi! Dear!! {{name}}<br/>",
    controller: [
      function(scope, elem, attr) {
        console.log("controller");
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <my-student></my-student>
  <my-student></my-student>
  <my-student></my-student>
  <my-student></my-student>
  <my-student></my-student>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

For further read I would suggest [angular documentation on directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: Thanks, that only I wanted to know. Kindly, vote up once, as some GG Idiot has voted down a legal question, which you rightly answered!

Comment: Also, can you pls throw light, why is array needed in directive-controller, unlike other entities like compile or link?